# Upper bound on solution of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation

$$ A x = b$$

where $A$ is an $m \times r$ matrix, $x$ is a vector of length $r$, and $b$ is a vector of length $m$ where $r \geq m$.

$A$ has a very special structure: all  of its entries are $\geq 1$ and its entries are increasing along the rows and down the columns, i.e. for all $i,j$, $a_{i,j} < a_{i+1,j}$ and $a_{i,j} < a_{i,j+1}$. b also has all elements greater than 1 and is also increasing element-wise.

**I would like to find an upper bound on $|x|$.**

I don't think this is possible for general $(A,b)$ but hope that it might be in this case.

Comment: If your matrix has more columns than rows then, assuming $Ax=b$ is consistent, there is no upper bound for the norm of $x$ unless you make your solution unique in some sense (e.g., the pseudo-inverse solution).

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel: Thanks for the comment. Suppose I can have $m=r$, so $A$ is a square matrix. Can we say anything more in this case?